# Paperclip::Error in RegistrationsController#update There was an error processing the thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

Paperclip::Error in RegistrationsController#update
There was an error processing the thumbnail. Can some one help me on this !!!
My registrations controller file is,

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected
    def update_resource(resource, params)
        resource.update_without_password(params)
    end
```

end

My application controller file is

```
     class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_paramters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_paramters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :fullname 
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :fullname <<  :current_password << :avatar
    end
end
```

Can someone help me to get rid of the error

My user model is,

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Comment: when you got this error?

Comment: can you show your migration for avatar?